# Is there somewhere else that might provide support of EOS

Tags: discussion

This place is deader than dead.

Any other venues for getting help?

Answer (score 0):

in no particular order, see below

plus any of the ubuntu forums are very useful

https://www.google.com

https://elementaryforums.com/index.php

https://github.com/orgs/elementary/discussions/categories/q-a

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/elementary-os-112/

https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/

Comment: Thank you
Stupid website

Comment: unfortunately most of them (perhaps with exception of reddit? seem equally quiet...